# Extension NSAttributedString Issue

Tags: ios, swift, nsattributedstring

I've lots of UITextfield and I want add a placeholder with different color. I'm trying to add extension instead of repeating the code every time to make it clean. I've written something like this but couldn't continue.

My code for `attributedPlaceholder` is

```
    emailTextField.attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string:"EMAIL ADDRESS",
        attributes:[NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.redColor()])
```

My extension:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

extension NSAttributedString {

class func attributedPlaceholderString(string: String, withColor color: UIColor) -> NSAttributedString {

    let attributedString =  NSAttributedString(string:string, attributes:[NSForegroundColorAttributeName: color])
    return attributedString
    }

}
```

but when I write

```
emailTextField.attributedPlaceholder.
```

I can't get the name of the class that I have created in the extension. Please where would be my issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code would be

```
emailTextField.attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString.attributedPlaceholderString("EMAIL ADDRESS", withColor: UIColor.redColor())
```

You have to take into account that you have created a class method (by using the `class` command), so you have to call that method on the class NSAttributedString

Comment: Please, if you think my answer is the correct one, select is as the correct answer :)

Comment: Yeah it working... I thought I can call the class after the dot.